# Django, can I force a request to bypass the cache, even if the cache key already exists

Tags: django, django-cache, django-caching

```
settings.py
['django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware'] + MIDDLEWARE + ['django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware']

middleware.py
    def middleware(request):
        if global_value % 2 == 1:
            # bypass cache, can I do something?
            response = get_response(request)
        else:
            response = get_response(request)
        return response
```

The reason is that we use certain values ​​in headers to distinguish which need cache（url is same）, but the cache cannot recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem by override FetchFromCacheMiddleware:
middleware.py

```
from django.middleware.cache import FetchFromCacheMiddleware

class MyFetchFromCacheMiddleware(FetchFromCacheMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if 'version' in request.headers:
            request._cache_update_cache = False
            return None  # Don't bother checking the cache.
        return super().process_request(request)
```

settings.py

```
    MIDDLEWARE = ['django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware'] + MIDDLEWARE + ['mobile_py.middleware.MyFetchFromCacheMiddleware']
```